# what is the best solution in this case

Tags: past-tense

Sorry I have not answered before because I was away from home, to answer to your question " how I heard from the band" , that's because I was looking through  the feral kid page when I saw your record, listened to it through bandcamp and decided to buy the first one you **did/ had release(d)** on your own . That's it

I think past perfect would be better than past simple (it will remove any ambiguities if there are some)  even if before buying a record it needs to be released so it is obvious than the release of the record was before the buying

Answer (score 1):

> you released

is fine because it is clear that you could not have bought the record before it was released. If the sequence of past actions is obvious, you need not use the past perfect to indicate sequence although of course you may. Therefore

> you had released

is also fine.

For some reason,

> you did release

is not idiomatic in this situation. My best guess is that using the modal in the affirmative indicative represents an intensifier, and an intensifier makes no sense in this context.